# Peano Arithmetic - Decidability

Tags: logic, foundations, peano-axioms, incompleteness, decidability

I need to show that if Peano Arithmetic does not decide a sentence $\varphi$ then the standard model
of Peano Arithmetic satisfies the negation of $\varphi$.
I know this partly has to do with Godel's Incompleteness Theorem, but I'm really lost on where to start. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT TO ADD:  "Let $\varphi$ be a $\Sigma_1$ sentence in the language of Peano Arithmetic" should be the first part of the problem, I left it out accidentally ^

Comment: That’s not true without assumptions on $\phi$, e.g. that it is $\Sigma_1$.

Comment: What do you mean by 'Peano arithmetic deciding a sentence $\varphi$'?

Comment: @Bram28 That's standard usage: a theory decides a sentence if it either proves or disproves that sentence.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen You are completely right, I left that out of my post on accident. Thanks!

Comment: @NoahSchweber Didn't know ... thanks! Always learn from you, Noah!! BTW: ... 'disproves' means 'proves the negation'?

Comment: @Bram28 Yup, exactly. (And dear lord logic needs to get its terminology together.)

Comment: To the OP again: [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)! (And if there's a symbol you don't know, the site [detexify](https://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) is super useful.)

Comment: @NoahSchweber Aha, so a complete theory decides every sentence then ... even if it is inconsistent?

Comment: @Bram28 Well, some-but-not-all texts include "consistent" in the definition of "complete" :P, but yes. (Seriously our terminology is the worst. Whyyyyyyyy.)

Comment: @NoahSchweber LOL ... but one more question. What if the theory is not recursive? Would it still be said to 'decide' a sentence? That seems counterintuitive (indeed, the whole notion that theories decide anything doesn't sit well with me anyway, but hey, if it's standard usage who am I to complain).  Or are there no such things as non-recursive theories? To be sure, I always understood a theory just a set of sentences.

Comment: @Bram28 Yup, it still decides it, and there are non-recursive theories. The two notions of "decides" are a priori unrelated. (They are connected after-the-fact in the sense that the set of sentences decided by a theory $T$ is r.e. - or if you prefer, *semidecidable* - relative to $T$. But that's a theorem. And a limited one at that: it only makes sense for theories in a countable language.) Incidentally, whether a theory is an arbitrary set of sentences or a deductively closed set of sentences ... depends on what text you're reading! The theorem above takes the more general usage.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Ah ... so a theory could 'decide' things in its (literally!) infinite wisdom! :)

Comment: @Noah It’s always entertained / frustrated me that a decidable theory and a decidable sentence are *completely* different ideas (not to mention the infamous two completely different notions of “complete” in the completeness theorem and incompleteness theorem).

Answer (score 1):

The only fact you need is that PA proves every true (i.e. true in the standard model) $\Sigma_1$ sentence. So if a $\Sigma_1$ sentence is undecidable in PA, it must be false.

This fact is somewhat tedious to prove, but I'm sure you have been given the hard part in some form. For instance, perhaps you've been given the fact that PA (or even the weak subtheory Robinson arithmetic) can correctly decide any instance of a computable relation. Then from there, you can use the fact that by definition, a $\Sigma_1$ sentence can be written $\exists x \varphi(x)$ for some $\varphi$ that is $\Delta_0$, hence computable. So if that's true, $\varphi(\mathbf n)$ is true for some $n,$ and since that's a $\Delta_0$ sentence, it can be proven in PA, and then PA can use existential instantiation to prove $\exists x\varphi(x)$ from there.

Comment: PA can't prove every true sentence in TA (true arithmetic, all the sensetences true in the standard model), because true arithmetic is not recursively axiomisable.

Comment: @user400188 I’m confused... did I say somewhere that it could?

Comment: Sorry, I might be mistaken. I don't the the definition of $\Sigma_1$ sentence. If it means computable sentence then this would work (please enlighten me if it does). I shouldn't have posted that comment.

Comment: @user400188 $\Sigma_1$ means of the form $\exists x \phi(x)$ where $\phi$ is recursive. e.g. "PA is inconsistent" is a $\Sigma_1$ sentence.